# 'this' pointer changes after calling a member function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I use Visual Studio 2012 Express to debug a 64-bit app. Let's say both 'foo' and 'bar' are some member functions of a class C.

'foo' looks like:

```
void foo() {
    bar();    // change to this->bar() works!
}
```

My program crashed because 'this' pointer is changed when it went inside 'bar'. The problem can be fixed by changing to 'this->bar()'.

Any idea how I should debug this problem? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean 'this pointer is changed'? Do you mean it no longer points to an instance of the class containing foo? Or a different instance?

Comment: please post a minimal but complete example

Answer (score 0):

You mean that the following code works?

```
void foo() {
    this->bar();    // instead of bar()
}
```

So, presuming foo() is a member function that calls another member function bar() for the same object, check two things: (1) whether there is another non-member function bar() having same signature of member function bar(), if so exist, change the non-member function name op always qualify with this-> for member function call as a good programming practice (2) When you call foo() for some object instance or pointer to object instance, check whether the object has been allocated and initialized properly.